# Yii - addInCondition

Tags: php, yii

first thing is i have these data in my db:

```
family_name      employee_rank
Dixon            1
Greene           1
Grimes           1
//and all other family_names with different employee_rank
```

i have a list of employees that i need to generate.
i have this condition in my $criteria where i am not including `employee_rank = 1` except `family_name = 'Grimes'`

```
$criteria->addNotInCondition('employee_rank', array('1'));
```

How can i include `family_name = "Grimes"` in the search condition.
i tried using

```
$criteria->addInCondition('family_name', array('Grimes'));
```

but this will only result to searching only Grimes and not include everyone else. I also tried using this

```
$criteria->addNotInCondition('employee_rank', array('9', '1'));
$criteria->addNotInCondition('family_name', array('Dixon', 'Greene'));
```

This is the correct thing that i want but i need a condition where i dont need to use `$criteria->addNotInCondition('family_name', array('Dixon', 'Greene'));` but a condition where `family_name = "Grimes"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail) methods `addNotInCondition` and `addInCondition` has third argument `$operator`.

```
$criteria->addNotInCondition('employee_rank', array('9', '1'), 'OR');
$criteria->compare('family_name', 'Grimes', false, 'OR');
```

Comment: wow. thanks @SiZE you are always to the rescue. i did not know that there is a third argument $operator.